# OTHER: {'EXIT',{error,timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.415>}}

Tags: objective-c, couchdb

I am an iphone/ipad developer, using objective c language, and I am
using couchDB for my application.

My issue is: if I delete my local couchDB (local database) or run for the first time,
I am getting the error:

```
OTHER: {'EXIT',{error,timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.415>}}
```

This is my workflow:

- my application replicates to remote iriscouch
  using                                xyz:a...@mmm.iriscouch.com/
  databasename.
- credentials are checked.
- if the replication is success, everything works as expected.
- if I reset my local couch database contents, and if I iterate the
  above step.
  'sometimes' I will get an error(mentioned below) and there will be no
  more synchronization with the remote. and its hard to re-sync the application.

This is that error from log:

```
[info] [<0.140.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - GET /_replicator/_changes? feed=continuous&heartbeat=300000&since=1 200

1> OTHER: {'EXIT',{error,timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.506>}}

1> OTHER: {'EXIT',{error,timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.507>}}

1>
```

waiting for your response

Krishna.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some validation functions running at destination end but in this case, this is the message returning from an erlang process tree timing out. But it needs to restart by itself after some (probably 5) seconds.